# How to hide URL Parameters being passed through link method (GeneXus)

Tags: url, parameters, hyperlink, hide, genexus

I'm sending some parameters via url from a webPanel to another using the link(&url) method, the values are being encrypted(source) and decrypted(destination), but I want to hide them from the user, that the only thing visible is the destination to the webPanel, not a thing should be visible after .aspx

How can I hide it?

Thanks.

Ps: it's a C#/SqlServer web environment

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use a [Websession](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?6321), that is to say: Store (Set Method)the parameters in the websession before calling the object and then read it in the start event of the called object (get Method).